# How to model toxicity curves

Tags: regression, modeling

I have curves, describing survival of cells in a toxic agent: One curve per cell line, the concentration of the agent on the x-axis and the fraction of survived cells on the y-axis:

[image: cell survival curves]

I'd like to draw a smooth curve through these points. I thought I might use [Hill equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_equation_(biochemistry)) (which is essentially a logistic function). However, logistic function is always $< 1$, while my survival curves start at exactly 1 and can even rise above (cells multiply, and there are measurement errors).

Or should I work with the absolute number of surviving cells? This is somewhat problematic, because experiments on different cell lines start with different number of cells:

[image: Cell count curves]

Comment: Could you plot the absolute number of surviving cells in the same way you've plotted the survival rates we can see how that looks?

Comment: Yes, sure, updated the question.

Comment: How do you obtain fractions that exceed 1 ??

Comment: @whuber: "cells multiply, and there are measurement errors"

Comment: It's crucial to elaborate on those measurement errors, because they play an essential role in identifying applicable modeling methods.

Comment: @whuber: We have no model for the errors. I'd go for normal distribution around the true values (true cell counts).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there will be a standard, simple model that does what you want to do. This is where dynamical systems based mathematical modelling approaches can be useful, but the solutions are often very complicated and don't lend very well to standard regression approaches.

If you literally just want a curve that fits and don't care about why or how, have you tried a normal distribution? Depending on where you cut it off on the left hand side, the normal distribution could go up, reach the 'mean', then trail off, or look sigmoidal? Might need a scaling parameter on the y axis.

Or you could just use a spline. A spline might work great here https://towardsdatascience.com/unraveling-spline-regression-in-r-937626bc3d96